# About constructor initialize sequence when using inheritance in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I am trying to do the exercise "reusing/E07_SimpleInheritance2" in "Thingking in Java 4th edition". the code works but the output in the console is:

```
A: New instance C
B: New instance B
C: New instance C
```

But I think C should be in front of B because the sentence "System.out.println('C: ' + str);" is in the C2's constructor, followed by instance B.   Well, why not?

OK, I just realized when initialize, the sequences is: (Static variables, static fields) > (variables, fields) > Constructors. That's the reason. Problem solved, thanks for the guys bellow :)

```
class A2{
    A2(String str){
        System.out.println("A: " + str);
    }
}

class B2{
    B2(String str){
        System.out.println("B: " + str);
    }
}

class C2 extends A2{
    C2(String str){
        super(str);
        System.out.println("C: " + str); //I think it should work first
    }
    B2 b = new B2("New instance B"); //Then followed by B
}
public class Q7_7_SimpleInheritance2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C2 c = new C2("New instance C");

    }

}
```

Comment: please add code for instantiation of your objects

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Ooops, I misread. Thought his problem was why "A" came before "B".

Answer (score 4):

When a `C2` instance is created, the first thing to happen is executing the `A2` (super class) constructor, which results in `A: New instance C` being printed first.

Then the instance variables of `C2` are initialized, before the body of `C2`'s constructor. Therefore `B2 b = new B2("New instance B");` is executed before `System.out.println("C: " + str);`, so `B: New instance B` is the second output line and `C: New instance C` the final line.

You may have been confused by the instance variable `b` being declared after the constructor, but that has no meaning.

Changing the code as follows may be less confusing, but would yield the exact same output:

```
class C2 extends A2 
{
    B2 b = new B2("New instance B");
    C2(String str){
        super(str);
        System.out.println("C: " + str);
    }
}
```

Comment: And the relevant JLS link : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5

Comment: Yes. I just realized when initialize, the sequences is: (Static variables, static fields) > (variables, fields) > Constructors. So whatever the b being declared...

Answer (score 2):

The key point here is that when instantiating a class the following happens(in this order):

1. `super` is called
2. class members are initialized
3. other constructor statements are executed

`2` and `3` explain why `B: New instance B` is printed before `C: New instance C`.

Answer (score -1):

A is before C because the constructor of C calls the constructor of A before writing to sysout.

Comment: The question was why is B before C.